# VBA for excel 2010, excel keeps crashing

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA for excel 2010 I Am attempting to check to see if a value in column C (created by a vlookup) is #N/A, and then take the value in column A in the corresponding row and put it in column D, the program shows no errors but Excel crashes every time I run it.

This is the code:

```
Sub casesVsQueue()      
                     Dim loop_counter As Integer
                 Dim colD_counter As Integer
                     loop_counter = 1
                     colD_counter = 2
do until isempty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & loop_counter).Value)
                 If iserror(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & loop_counter).Value) Then
                        Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range("D"& colD_counter).value = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A" & loop_counter).value
                        loop_counter = loop_counter + 1

        End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: if you the code line-by-line (stepping through) where does it crash?

Comment: Move `loop_counter = loop_counter + 1 ` after the `End If`.  Being inside it never moves to the next row and keeps looping.

Comment: And replace the stylized quotes in this line `Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range("D"& colD_counter).value = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A" & loop_counter).value` they will stop your code.

Comment: @ScottCraner - what do you mean by *stylized quotes*?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman look at the quotes around Sheet1.  The are Chr(147) and not Chr(34).  I know in formulas it makes a difference.  I believe in vba it will cause an error.

Comment: Ah, I see now @ScottCraner.

Comment: aka "Smart Quotes" - typically see these if you've copy-pasted through Word or similar...   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark

Comment: I really, really, *really* hope your code isn't *actually* indented like that, it's literally *asking* for bugs. Properly indented code is **much** easier to read, follow, understand, maintain, ...and debug.

Comment: It's not I copy &I pasted

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments above:

Three things:

1. The loop_counter needs to be outside the If. Otherwise as soon as the If does not resolve true it will loop on the same cell till the user shuts down Excel.
2. The "Smart Quotes" need to be changed to regular quotes.  As Tim Williams stated this usually comes from copy and paste through another medium like Word.
3. The colD_counter was missing.  Without this the output would always be put in the same cell.

The Code:

```
Sub casesVsQueue()
    Dim loop_counter As Integer
    Dim colD_counter As Integer

    loop_counter = 1
    colD_counter = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & loop_counter).Value)
        If IsError(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & loop_counter).Value) Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & colD_counter).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & loop_counter).Value
            colD_counter = colD_counter + 1
        End If
        loop_counter = loop_counter + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```